Playwright Node :How to accept cookies when scrawling?
I cannot scrape content because of the cookies. I have been researching and context.addCookies seems to be the way to do it but I still cant get to the content. If I log the html received after I add the cookies, Im only seeing the page with the cookies banner, so cookies were not accepted. What am I doing wrong?
const getHtml = () => {
  const browser = await {chromium}["chromium"].launch({headless: false});
  const context = await browser.newContext();
  const page = await context.newPage()
  await page.goto(url);

  await page.waitForLoadState("networkidle");

  const  cookies = await context.cookies()
  await context.addCookies(cookies)

  const html = await page.content();
  await context.close();
  await browser.close();
  return html;
}



There's no way to help without the actual page, a sample page. But did you try clicking the cookie accept banner? Right now, you're adding the same cookies you extracted, which I don't expect would achieve anything.

Thank you, I also realized that. I have also attempted to just add the cookies manually (looking up which cookies have been added and then adding them with await context.addCookies([name: 'someName', value: 'someValue', domain: '.website.de', path: '/', {...}]) but that also didnt do anything. I also tried: await page.click('text=Accept all'); which seemed to work at first but then not anymore

I also tried locating the accept button and clicking like this: if (await page.locator('.className').isEnabled()) {await page.click('.className')} . It does find the accept button with the classNae but doesnt seem to click it

Please see my first comment. No page, no can help.
